# Type mismatch after upgrading SBT

Tags: scala, sbt, migration

I am trying to upgrade a historic Scala/Spark SBT project to SBT version 1.1.0. It uses Scala 2.10.6, as specified in the `build.sbt` file. It is unclear for which SBT version the `build.sbt` file was implemented, but presumably 0.12.x or even earlier.

I fail to migrate the `assemblyExcludedJars` line in the `build.sbt` file:

```
import sbt.Keys.{libraryDependencies, _}
import sbtassembly.AssemblyKeys.assemblyExcludedJars

[...]

lazy val sparkSettings = Seq(
  libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
      "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "1.6.0",
      [...],
  assemblyExcludedJars in assembly <<= (fullClasspath in assembly) map { cp =>
val excludes = Set(
  "minlog-1.2.jar",
  [...]
)
cp filter { jar => excludes(jar.data.getName) }
  }
)
```

As pointed out in the [migration guide](https://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Migrating-from-sbt-012x.html), the `<<=` is no longer supported, so I changed it to `:=`.

When I run `sbt assembly` after the change, the following error is thrown:

```
$ sbt assembly
[info] Loading settings from idea.sbt ...
[info] Loading global plugins from /home/XXX/.sbt/1.0/plugins
[info] Loading settings from assembly.sbt ...
[info] Loading project definition from YYY/project
YYY/build.sbt:49: error: type mismatch;
 found   : sbt.Def.Initialize[sbt.Task[Seq[sbt.internal.util.Attributed[java.io.File]]]]
 required: sbt.Keys.Classpath
(which expands to)  Seq[sbt.internal.util.Attributed[java.io.File]]
  assemblyExcludedJars in assembly := (fullClasspath in assembly) map { cp =>
                                                              ^
[error] sbt.compiler.EvalException: Type error in expression
[error] sbt.compiler.EvalException: Type error in expression
[error] Use 'last' for the full log.
Project loading failed: (r)etry, (q)uit, (l)ast, or (i)gnore?
```

I could not find a lot in the SBT documentation about what exactly this line is supposed to do. I find it rather confusing though that the type of `assembly` seems to have changed.

I am also looking at this in IntelliJ Idea, but it actually indicates an error `Cannot resolve symbol assembly`.

How can I migrate this build file correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To rewrite the `assemblyExcludedJars` setting it should look something like this:

```
assemblyExcludedJars in assembly := { 
  val cp = (fullClasspath in assembly).value
  val excludes = Set("minlog-1.2.jar", [...])
  cp filter { jar => excludes(jar.data.getName) }
}
```

Just replacing the `<<=` operator will fail because the `:=` operator takes the result type of the task on the right-hand side instead of an `Initialize[Task[...]]`

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes `assemblyExcludedJars` doesn't work.

The dirty way is to use defind in merge strategy.

```
assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly :={
    case PathList("lib", "static", "Windows", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.discard
    case PathList("META-INF", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.discard
    case PathList("com","sun", xs @ _*)=> MergeStrategy.discard
    case PathList("mx4j", xs @ _*)=> MergeStrategy.discard
    case PathList("org","aopalliance", xs @ _*)=> MergeStrategy.discard
    case PathList("org","apache","jasper", xs @ _*)=> MergeStrategy.discard
    case PathList("javax", xs @ _*)=> MergeStrategy.discard
    case PathList("org", "apache", "jasper", xs @ _*)=> MergeStrategy.discard
    case PathList("org", "fusesource", xs @ _*)=> MergeStrategy.discard
    case PathList("org", "objenesis", xs @ _*)=> MergeStrategy.discard
    case PathList("org", "scalactic", xs @ _*)=> MergeStrategy.discard
    case PathList("org", "scalactic", xs @ _*)=> MergeStrategy.discard
    case PathList("parquet",  xs @ _*)=> MergeStrategy.discard
    case PathList("javax", xs @ _*)=> MergeStrategy.discard
    case PathList("org", "apache", "jasper", xs @ _*)=> MergeStrategy.discard
    case PathList("org", "fusesource", xs @ _*)=> MergeStrategy.discard
    case PathList("org", "objenesis", xs @ _*)=> MergeStrategy.discard
    case PathList("org", "scalactic", xs @ _*)=> MergeStrategy.discard
    case PathList("parquet",  xs @ _*)=> MergeStrategy.discard
    case PathList("akka",  xs @ _*)=> MergeStrategy.discard
    case PathList("antlr",  xs @ _*)=> MergeStrategy.discard
    case PathList("assets",  xs @ _*)=> MergeStrategy.discard
    case PathList("au",  xs @ _*)=> MergeStrategy.discard
    case PathList("breeze",  xs @ _*)=> MergeStrategy.discard
    case PathList("codegen",  xs @ _*)=> MergeStrategy.discard
    case PathList("contribs",  xs @ _*)=> MergeStrategy.discard
    case PathList("darwin",  xs @ _*)=> MergeStrategy.discard
    case PathList("db",  xs @ _*)=> MergeStrategy.discard
    case PathList("edu",  xs @ _*)=> MergeStrategy.discard
    case PathList("fr",  xs @ _*)=> MergeStrategy.discard
    case PathList("hbase-webapps",  xs @ _*)=> MergeStrategy.discard
    case PathList("html",  xs @ _*)=> MergeStrategy.discard
    case PathList("i18n",  xs @ _*)=> MergeStrategy.discard
    case PathList("images",  xs @ _*)=> MergeStrategy.discard
    case PathList("io",  xs @ _*)=> MergeStrategy.discard
    case PathList("javaewah",  xs @ _*)=> MergeStrategy.discard
    case PathList("javassist",  xs @ _*)=> MergeStrategy.discard
    case PathList("javolution",  xs @ _*)=> MergeStrategy.discard
    case PathList("jersey",  xs @ _*)=> MergeStrategy.discard
    case PathList("jline",  xs @ _*)=> MergeStrategy.discard
    case PathList("jodd",  xs @ _*)=> MergeStrategy.discard
    case PathList("joptsimple",  xs @ _*)=> MergeStrategy.discard
    case PathList("junit",  xs @ _*)=> MergeStrategy.discard
    case PathList("kafka",  xs @ _*)=> MergeStrategy.discard
    case PathList("linux",  xs @ _*)=> MergeStrategy.discard
    case PathList("macrocompat",  xs @ _*)=> MergeStrategy.discard
    case PathList("mozilla",  xs @ _*)=> MergeStrategy.discard
    case PathList("net",  xs @ _*)=> MergeStrategy.discard
    case PathList("nu",  xs @ _*)=> MergeStrategy.discard
    case PathList("ooyala",  xs @ _*)=> MergeStrategy.discard
    case PathList("OSGI-OPT",  xs @ _*)=> MergeStrategy.discard
    case PathList("py4j",  xs @ _*)=> MergeStrategy.discard
    case PathList("scala",  xs @ _*)=> MergeStrategy.discard
    case PathList("schema",  xs @ _*)=> MergeStrategy.discard
    case PathList("shaded",  xs @ _*)=> MergeStrategy.discard
    case PathList("shapeless",  xs @ _*)=> MergeStrategy.discard
    case PathList("snappydata",  xs @ _*)=> MergeStrategy.discard
    case PathList("spark",  xs @ _*)=> MergeStrategy.discard
    case PathList("spire",  xs @ _*)=> MergeStrategy.discard
    case PathList("spray",  xs @ _*)=> MergeStrategy.discard
    case PathList("tables",  xs @ _*)=> MergeStrategy.discard
    case PathList("templates",  xs @ _*)=> MergeStrategy.discard
    case PathList("twitter4j",  xs @ _*)=> MergeStrategy.discard
    case PathList("webapps",  xs @ _*)=> MergeStrategy.discard
    case PathList("win32",  xs @ _*)=> MergeStrategy.discard
    case PathList("org", "antlr",xs @ _*)=> MergeStrategy.discard
    case PathList("org", "bouncycastle",xs @ _*)=> MergeStrategy.discard
    case PathList("org", "cliffc",xs @ _*)=> MergeStrategy.discard
    case PathList("org", "cloudera",xs @ _*)=> MergeStrategy.discard
    case PathList("org", "codehaus",xs @ _*)=> MergeStrategy.discard
    case PathList("org", "datanucleus",xs @ _*)=> MergeStrategy.discard
    case PathList("org", "dmg",xs @ _*)=> MergeStrategy.discard
    case PathList("org", "eclipse",xs @ _*)=> MergeStrategy.discard
    case PathList("org", "eigenbase",xs @ _*)=> MergeStrategy.discard
    case PathList("org", "flywaydb",xs @ _*)=> MergeStrategy.discard
    case PathList("org", "glassfish",xs @ _*)=> MergeStrategy.discard
    case PathList("org", "h2",xs @ _*)=> MergeStrategy.discard
    case PathList("org", "hamcrest",xs @ _*)=> MergeStrategy.discard
    case PathList("org", "I0Itec",xs @ _*)=> MergeStrategy.discard
    case PathList("org", "iq80",xs @ _*)=> MergeStrategy.discard
    case PathList("org", "jamon",xs @ _*)=> MergeStrategy.discard
    case PathList("org", "jboss",xs @ _*)=> MergeStrategy.discard
    case PathList("org", "jcodings",xs @ _*)=> MergeStrategy.discard
    case PathList("org", "jets3t",xs @ _*)=> MergeStrategy.discard
    case PathList("org", "joda",xs @ _*)=> MergeStrategy.discard
    case PathList("org", "joni",xs @ _*)=> MergeStrategy.discard
    case PathList("org", "jpmml",xs @ _*)=> MergeStrategy.discard
    case PathList("org", "junit",xs @ _*)=> MergeStrategy.discard
    case PathList("org", "jvnet",xs @ _*)=> MergeStrategy.discard
    case PathList("org", "j_paine",xs @ _*)=> MergeStrategy.discard
    case PathList("org", "mortbay",xs @ _*)=> MergeStrategy.discard
    case PathList("org", "netlib",xs @ _*)=> MergeStrategy.discard
    case PathList("org", "omg",xs @ _*)=> MergeStrategy.discard
    case PathList("org", "osgi",xs @ _*)=> MergeStrategy.discard
    case PathList("org", "parboiled",xs @ _*)=> MergeStrategy.discard
    case PathList("org", "parboiled2",xs @ _*)=> MergeStrategy.discard
    case PathList("org", "roaringbitmap",xs @ _*)=> MergeStrategy.discard
    case PathList("org", "rogach",xs @ _*)=> MergeStrategy.discard
    case PathList("org", "scalatest",xs @ _*)=> MergeStrategy.discard
    case PathList("org", "stringtemplate",xs @ _*)=> MergeStrategy.discard
    case PathList("org", "supercsv",xs @ _*)=> MergeStrategy.discard
    case PathList("org", "tukaani",xs @ _*)=> MergeStrategy.discard
    case PathList("org", "uncommons",xs @ _*)=> MergeStrategy.discard
    case PathList("org", "w3c",xs @ _*)=> MergeStrategy.discard
    case PathList("org", "xerial",xs @ _*)=> MergeStrategy.discard
    case PathList("org", "znerd",xs @ _*)=> MergeStrategy.discard
    case PathList("org", "clearspring",xs @ _*)=> MergeStrategy.discard
    case PathList("org", "esotericsoftware",xs @ _*)=> MergeStrategy.discard
    case PathList("org", "facebook",xs @ _*)=> MergeStrategy.discard
    case PathList("org", "fasterxml",xs @ _*)=> MergeStrategy.discard
    case PathList("com", "gemstone",xs @ _*)=> MergeStrategy.discard
    case PathList("com", "github",xs @ _*)=> MergeStrategy.discard
    case PathList("com", "jamesmurty",xs @ _*)=> MergeStrategy.discard
    case PathList("com", "jolbox",xs @ _*)=> MergeStrategy.discard
    case PathList("com", "ning",xs @ _*)=> MergeStrategy.discard
    case PathList("com", "pivotal",xs @ _*)=> MergeStrategy.discard
    case PathList("com", "thoughtworks",xs @ _*)=> MergeStrategy.discard
    case PathList("com", "univocity",xs @ _*)=> MergeStrategy.discard
    case PathList("com", "vmware",xs @ _*)=> MergeStrategy.discard
    case PathList("com", "yammer",xs @ _*)=> MergeStrategy.discard
    case PathList("com", "zaxxer",xs @ _*)=> MergeStrategy.discard
    case x => MergeStrategy.first
}
```